# Why he couldn't take Davy Jones hand back from the gallows?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, at-worlds-end

In the movie *"At World's End"* Davy Jones visits Calypso (Tia Dalma) at the gallows where she touches him to turn him into human form a moment; at this moment he reaches for her and suddenly he turns back and finds his hand is stucky yet he phases through gallows to free himself.

My question is why he couldn't take his hand back since everything is intangible  for him.

Is there any explanation in the movie?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Davy Jones AWE]

IMO the idea is that he literally turned human for moment, because he remembered his "love" for her (moment when the curse is undone) when she touched him (she may have magic too, but it could be "love" related magic), but suddenly, he emotionally caught himself and reflexes back into the being he has become (physically and psychologically) by remembering (from his perspective) he has been betrayed by a sea goddess...

*"Part of the ship, Part of the crew."*

So as a human man, he doesn't have the supernatural abilities to "pass through" as he does either as The Captain of the Flying Dutchman or as the "corrupt" Captain of the Flying Dutchman (because Davy Jones became a creature, because he did not do his job required as The Captain of the Flying Dutchman and ferry the souls of the dead to the other side) -- So once he was reminded of his pain, the curse, and powers with it, ensued even though he struggles with it. We also see that all of people whom work on the crew for Jones (under his curse) also become "creatures", but unlike Jones (because they are not the Captain), they eventually literally become apart of the ship--but he too may be apart of ship and can use it to "free" himself, being a different part, a part none the less...

[image: Crew Member]

*At World's End* not only sets up a redemption ark for Jack Sparrow, but it also confirms that "love" is a key competent and thematic to the series, as the series explores love-torn situations and/or may be asking if love can ever conquer all or is it a limitation that only ever causes pain?

[image: Angelica]

[image: Jack Voodoo Doll]